# Autokey (autokey-qt) not listening to key commands but works fine from mouse menu

Tags: kubuntu, autokey

I'm running kubuntu and have been using autokey successfully for years, but a while back a system update broke it. I originally tried to just wait it out and see if a fix would be pushed.

Now, 6 months later, I'm still unable to auto insert text using key command cues.  However, if I click on the autokey symbol in the system tray and select the phrase I'm trying to insert it works fine.

Running autokey-qt from the shell produces the following:

```
enter<class 'Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension'>
<class 'Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension'>
Exception in thread KeypressHandler-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/iomediator.py", line 204, in run
    target.handle_keypress(rawKey, modifiers, key, windowName, windowClass)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 179, in handle_keypress
    currentInput, windowInfo, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/service.py", line 304, in __checkTextMatches
    if item.check_input(buffer, windowInfo):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 735, in check_input
    abbr = self._should_trigger_abbreviation(buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 134, in _should_trigger_abbreviation
    if self.__checkInput(buffer, abbr):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 147, in __checkInput
    stringBefore, typedAbbr, stringAfter = self._partition_input(buffer, abbr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/autokey/model.py", line 194, in _partition_input
    stringBefore, typedAbbr, stringAfter = currentString.rpartition(abbr)
ValueError: empty separator
```

How can I get autokey to recognize text based cues again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this "empty separator" error I had to dig though the hidden files in my `~/.config/autokey/data` sub-folders

***hint 1:*** the filenames begin with a `.`

***hint 2:*** start with your newest phrases as they are the most likely culpret.

Inside the text files there is a section that should look like:

```
    "abbreviations": [
        ",a", 
        ",alpha"
    ],
```

Where the `,a` and the `,alpha` above correspond to the key sequence that triggers the insertion of your corresponding phrase.

However in an offending 'Phrase' rule there will be an extra blank entry in the 'abbreviation' section as follows

```
"abbreviations": [
    ",a", 
    ",alpha",
    ""
],
```

Delete the quoted blank `""` and proceeding comma `,`

Save the file and restart Autokey, and it should now work.